# Why will my bootstrap 3.7 carousel not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been following a guide on how to implement this feature of bootstrap and for the life of me I can't figured out why it isn't working. I have all of the CDNs linked in my header and the Js Script linked. All of them are directly copied from the bootstrap website.

```
<div id="productCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#productCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#productCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#productCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#productCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="../../static/images/city.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="../../static/images/city.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="../../static/images/city.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="../../static/images/city.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#productCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#productCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code an everything works fine.

Check how you embed the libraries.

1. Boostrap CSS
2. jQuery
3. Bootstrap JS

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="productCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#productCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#productCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#productCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#productCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#productCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#productCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Somehow I missed the Jquery library without noticing it, thanks for pointing that out(its in a seperate template)